# Why won't this dock produce grain?

Tags: openttd

As can be seen in the image below, the ship can access both docks.

[image]

Comment: Everything looks like it should work. Has the ship been refitted to carry grain?

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann No I didn't X( I can be so oblivious to the most obvious things sometimes :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just so we have an answer here:

In order for a resource to produce, the station/dock/loading bay attached to it needs to have been visited by a transporter fitted out to carry that type of resource. In this instance, a ship must have visited the dock that has been fitted out to carry grain.

Once that has happened, the resource will start delivering produce to your dock.

This can be altered by the settings in the station window by chaning **Deliver cargo to a station only when there is a demand** (under cargo handling) to Off

Comment: I like very beaucoup your surnom ;-)

Comment: @LucM You mean je beaucoup aime ;)